# 実行ボタン等のval buttonEqualがエラーになってしまう

Tags: android, kotlin

電卓アプリを開発していますが、エラーが発生して進めなくなってしまったため、質問させていただきます。

MainActivity.kt の方の実行ボタン等の `val buttonEqual` が赤線で、エラー表記になってしまうことに困っています。
説明の仕方が悪く、すみません。

activity _main.xml

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/equal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="=" />
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/clear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="c"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/formula"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:height="250dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </TableRow>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
        /* 数字ボタン */
        val buttonZero: Button = findViewById(R.id.num0)
        val buttonOne: Button = findViewById(R.id.num1)
        val buttonTwo: Button = findViewById(R.id.num2)
        val buttonThree: Button = findViewById(R.id.num3)
        val buttonFour: Button = findViewById(R.id.num4)
        val buttonFive: Button = findViewById(R.id.num5)
        val buttonSix: Button = findViewById(R.id.num6)
        val buttonSeven: Button = findViewById(R.id.num7)
        val buttonEight: Button = findViewById(R.id.num8)
        val buttonNine: Button = findViewById(R.id.num9)

        /* 計算ボタン */
        val buttonAdd : Button = findViewById(R.id.add)
        val buttonMul : Button = findViewById(R.id.mul)
        val buttonSub : Button = findViewById(R.id.sub)
        val buttonDiv :Button = findViewById(R.id.div)

        /* 実行ボタン */
        val buttonEqual :Button = findViewById(R.id.equal) //56行目

        /* クリアボタン */
        val buttonClear : Button = findViewById(R.id.clear) //59行目

        /* 表示テキスト */
        val textArea : TextView = findViewById(R.id.formula) //62行目
```

ソースと同じものが写真で赤線になってしまいます

[image: ソースと同じものが写真で赤線になってしまいます]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　より答えやすい質問にするため、ふたつお願いをさせてください。(1) どのようなエラーが出たのか [edit] して追記してください。単に「エラーが出た」だけだと状況が掴みにくいです。(2) ソースコードは写真ではなくて、テキストとしてコピー＆ペーストしてください。回答者がエラーを再現しやすくなります。どうぞよろしくお願いします :)

Comment: 申し訳ありません。編集し直します。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 赤線にマウスカーソルを当てるなどするとエラーの内容が出るんじゃないかと思うのですが、何と出ましたでしょうか。

Comment: – nekketsuuuさん コメントありがとうございます。無事解決しました。お恥ずかしながら、スペルミス等を修正したところ、正常に動作しました。

Comment: 良かったです。お疲れ様でした。自己解決した場合、スタック・オーバーフローでは自己回答もでき、また推奨しています。よろしければご自身で回答を作ってみてください :)